# Nested select statement in Sql

Tags: sql, select, view, nested, subquery

How would I nest a select statement within a select statement with a group by?

Example:

```
Select 
    Name, Manager, Company
From
    (Select 
         Name, Manager, Company, Detail
     From 
         dbo.company as Co
     Inner Join
         dbo.contact as Cnt on Co.id = Cnt.company_id)
Group By 
    Name, manager, Company
```

The query is much more complex. Is it SQL?

I only want to show the first select statement but it references the nested select statement.

Comment: Sure. The nested query is called a derived table.  The basic syntax is `select <stuff > from (select <stuff from <some tables>) t`.  You just have to alias the derived table.

Comment: This is not clear. It's not clear what things you are referring to or what you are trying to say about them. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Debug questions require a [mre]. Please justify what you expect or don't expect by referencing competent documentation. Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. PS Your post had the same code & some prose appearing twice. Did you mean to talk about 2 different queries? Please before publishing look at the formatted version of your post. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you a derivative table.

Here is a exemple for your need in SQL:

```sql
SELECT derivative_table.Name, derivative_table.Manager, derivative_table.Company
FROM (
    SELECT c.Name, c.Manager, c.Company, COUNT(*) as Count
    FROM dbo.company c
    INNER JOIN Dbo.contact ct ON c.id = ct.company_id
    GROUP BY c.Name, c.Manager, c.Company
) AS derivative_table
WHERE derivative_table.Count > 1
```